# Hiding or Removing the contracted icon [+] for rowGroup based on condition in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid-react

We are using ag-grid-enterprise 13.1.0.

We have parent and children rows (get expanded on clicking the plus '+' symbol on parent row).

We When there is no data for the children rows, they are displayed as empty rows. In this case I would like to hide / remove the + icon, so that user will not expand to see the empty child row.

Could you let us know if this is possible or any other suitable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I have achieved this using rowClassRules property. Below is the piece of code:**

```
rowClassRules = {
        "manualExpand": function(params) {
          if(params.node.field === 'outageName' && params.node.expanded === false) {
            var expandFlag = checkForEmptySevone(params.node)
            return expandFlag;
          }
        },

        "expandAll": function(params) {
          if (params.node.field === 'outageName' && params.node.expanded === true) {
            var expandAllFlag = checkForEmptySevone(params.node)
            return expandAllFlag;
          }
        }
      },

      checkForEmptySevone = (node) => {
        var rowData = node.childrenAfterGroup[0].data;
        if(rowData.get('SEVONE_ID') === ' ' || rowData.get('SEVONE_ID') === '' || 
          rowData.get('SEVONE_ID') === undefined || rowData.get('SEVONE_ID') === null) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
      }

**Below is the css:**
.manualExpand  .ag-icon-expanded {
    display: none !important;
}

.manualExpand  .ag-group-value {
    padding-left: 16px !important;
}

.manualExpand  .ag-icon-contracted {
    display: none !important;
}

.expandAll  .ag-icon-expanded {
    display: none !important;
}

.expandAll  .ag-group-value {
    padding-left: 16px !important;
}

.expandAll  .ag-icon-contracted {
    display: none !important;
}

.expandAll + div {
    background-color: black;
    display: none ! important;
}
```